# How do I allow only scrolling upwards and disable scrolling downwards?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have an event listener and you can scroll on my webpage until `window.scrollY` is larger than 50. If you reach the 50 with window.scrollY, then you are only allowed to scroll upwards. If you are e.g. at 47 then you can scroll downwards to 50 again. I currently implemented it with `window.scroll(0, 50);` to prevent scrolling below 50, but if you try to scroll below 50 the webpage is jumpy/glitchy. Do you have any suggestions?

```js
onScroll() {
  this.scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  this.newValue = window.pageYOffset;
  if (window.scrollY > 50) {
    if (this.oldValue < this.newValue) {
      // Do not scroll below 50
      window.scroll(0, 50);
    }
  }
  this.oldValue = this.newValue;
}
```

[Overview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0WZ8.png)
As you can see in the image, there is an overlay menu. The menu appears on top of the contents after pressing an icon.

Comment: Btw, if you disable scrolling down, there's no need for scrolling up.

Comment: It's a very strange question. If there is content on the page why you can't scroll down to see it?

Comment: @Azu There is a menu at the top, and you should be able to scroll through the menu. There is content below the menu that should be visible, but not scrollable. I tried to fix it by using css but this doesn't work.

Comment: `html { height: calc(100% + 50px); }`

Comment: @loop Thank you for your response. But I am looking for a JavaScript solution. The webpage is too complex for this solution.

Comment: @Azu I added an image to my question for clarification.

Comment: So you want to scroll the menu, not the page when you roll the mouse wheel?

Comment: @Azu Yes, exactly. But disabling scroll (with css) on the entire body and enabling scroll (with css) on the div of the menu doesn't work on the webpage. Therefore I thought that setting a 'maximum' scroll position at the end of the menu was maybe a solution.

Comment: Try this. Give the menu fixed height and overflow-y: auto. In this way if the height is less than the menu height you'll get a scroll. When the user is on the menu it will scroll down, not the page.